# Composite WPF: Data Template vs. View Model Injection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, datatemplate

Here is the simple question: what do you use to link your views to your view models?

Basically there is 2 common ways of achieving that, data templates and view model injection (samples below).

**What I would like to know is why do you prefer a method over the other and in which case you use them. Precise the MVVM framework you use.**

---

The data template way or "View Model first" approach (Resources.xaml):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:PersonViewModel}">
    <my:PersonView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The view model injection way or "View first" approach  (PersonView.xaml.cs):

```
[Import]
public PersonViewModel ViewModel
{
    set
    {
        this.DataContext = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I prefer using DataTemplates

- It allows me to set multiple Views for the same ViewModel based on a property
- My ViewModels are my application, and the View is nothing more than a pretty layer that makes my ViewModel's User-Friendly. If I use ViewModel injection, than the Views become my application and the development team suddenly has to worry about the UI side of things
- My ViewModels are managed by other ViewModels. For example, one ViewModel might contain a collection of other ViewModels that get displayed in a TabControl. Adding or Closing tabs is done within the parent ViewModel. This sort of thing is not easily accomplished with the View controlling the application state.
- I can initialize different ViewModels using parameterized constructors based on my needs instead of having to use generic Import ones

That's just a few reasons... I'm sure there's others but they don't come to mind right now

Comment: @Ucodia I usually use PRISM, although I sometimes use the MVVM Light Framework because their `RelayCommand` raises a PropertyChanged event on commands when the `CanExecute` parameters change, and PRISM's `DelegateCommand` does not.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then do you use the Region feature of Prism? Because this is a really interesting feature of Prism, but this one uses a kind of "view first" approach.

Comment: @Ucodia I have used it occasionally for the application shell, but I don't use it beyond that. For example, I might have a Menu region and a Content region, since I know that whatever happens with the application those two pieces will always be static

Comment: @Rachel: One question re: _"My ViewModels are my application"_: How do you deal with the application's main window and popup windows / dialog boxes? As far as I understand it, displaying a view model in a new window would require something like `new Window() { Content = windowViewModel }.Show()` -- won't that pollute your application, which is supposed to consist only of view models?

Comment: @stakx I'm not a big fan of multiple windows in WPF, and typically have been fine with solutions such as [this](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) where I have properties like `IsDialogOpen` and `DialogContext` for telling the View to display a "popup". But if I ever came across a case where I did need multiple windows or top-level dialogs, I'd probably look into coding some kind of  service that handles window/dialog management for the application. That's usually what I see recommended for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

We use a view model first approach because we find it easier to manage, particular on larger scale enterprise apps. We use [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) to take care of view location and binding.

Answer (score 0):

I use both. DataTemplates for small projects, but for larger or team projects we use view model injection.